# Give career-users a clear and shareable URL to show their profiles

Tags: feature-request, jobs, profile-page

### Problem

It's a pain in the ... leg to show somebody your carreers.stackoverflow-profile. Simply because it's unclear how to do this. Even after using careers.so for weeks i'm still using the print-button (!) to share my profile, and I doubt it's the intented usage for profile sharing.

### Solution

Show a button/notice/icon within your carreers.stackoverflow-profile that clearly gives users a shareable link to their profile.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for this the other day and it took way too long to find. The Careers UI needs work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There already is such a link.

Click on 'privacy settings':

<kbd>[image: privacy settings link]</kbd>

Here you can create a readable public link:

<kbd>[image: public link options]</kbd>

Comment: Excellent! But, this should be much more obvious! I'm working in UI/Frontend for 10 years and wasn't able to find it.

Comment: We're going to be making this way more obvious.  It's too hard to find now.